# How do I join to a "fixed vector" in SQL?

Tags: sql, ms-access

By "fixed vector" I mean a static list of values, like 1 through 24.

The current query looks like this (simplified)

```
SELECT Period, Profit FROM Projections
```

But the data is "sparse" — so there's not a row for every period.

What query will give me a row for peiods 1-24 every time, with zeros (or NULLs) where there's no data?

I would like to do this with just the query to avoid a mess of client code.

Thanks!

Comment: Depending on the context in which you want to do this, you might be able to use an ADO disconnected recordset, which can basically be anything you like, i.e., not dependent on a data table.

Comment: You'd have to add the column to the disconnected recordset using the MsDataShape OLE DB provider then iterate through the fetched rows to replace the NULLs with the required values. In other words, a pointless exercise. The fabricated 'DATA' table in SQL code is the way to go, IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a udf called udfRange(start int,count int) or something like that, and left-join to the output of the function.

Or for something really quick and dirty, you could join to a subselect that looked like

```
SELECT DATA.Period, P.Profit
FROM (
SELECT 1 AS Period
UNION SELECT 2
...
UNION SELECT 24) AS DATA 
LEFT JOIN Projections P ON DATA.Period = P.Period
```

Comment: I had something like this in mind among my "last resorts", and it looks like it's going to work.  It's even more onerous in Access, though, because you can't just SELECT 1, you have to include a FROM clause.  Still, I prefer it to the alternatives.  Thanks!

Comment: +1 for the fabricated table ('DATA') approach (harpo is correct: you need a FROM clause, preferable using a table you *know* always has one row, otherwise use the DISTINCT keyword; but if you used an empty table you would end up with a zero row table -- not good!)

Answer (score 1):

Why not create a 'Periods' lookup table, with values 1 - 24 (and any other columns that might be relevant, like a description of the period, or its name) then do a left outer join between the Periods lookup table and your projections table.

Comment: Mainly because it's not really "data" (and it's not my database).  I can accomplish the report in a read-only manner, but as I said it will just take more client code.

Comment: The possible periods most certainly do constitute "data". This is a pretty common approach.