# Android - sqlite in clause using values from array which contains same values multiple times

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

I want to execute a sqlite query:

```
select * from table_name where id in (23,33,33,55,43,23);
```

if any value is appearing in the array twice, cursor should contain the corresponding row twice.

Comment: what r u getting ? single row?

Comment: try to get distinct data from table.

Comment: Or should i just run the query in a for loop?

Comment: I am getting each row only one time. The array contains same id twice. So i want that row shown in the cursor two times.

Comment: the data is not distinct, i just want it two times.

Comment: @JossyPaul I think it is working. install "SQLITEMAN' and execute your code

Comment: It will only check the row's someID against the values of the IN().

It doesn't matter how your IN() looks like, it will not return more results than there are rows that matches that value

Answer (score 1):

Yes run a for loop or use a join:

```
SELECT T.*
FROM (
  SELECT 23 AS id
  UNION SELECT 33
  ...
  UNION SELECT 23) AS list
LEFT JOIN table_name T ON list.id = T.id
```

Based on this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/372991/360211